# Convert escaped string to json object in java

Tags: java, json, string, parsing, unescapestring

I have a string that looks like this..

```
"Message" : "{\"eventType\":\"DataChanged\",\"operation\":\"create\"}"
```

Is there any library in Java that can convert this to the string below so I can then parse it into a json object

```
"Message" : {"eventType":"DataChanged","operation":"create"}
```

Comment: Your JSON parser can. The value of Message is a string. You can parse this string as JSON.

Comment: You can use Fasterxml library to parse this string to JSON

Comment: Have you used JObject.Parse({string}) ?

Comment: Probably not.  The first one doesn't look right.  Some of your quote marks (`"`) are escaped and some aren't.  If that's the _content_ of your `String`, then it's not valid json.  If that's the _declaration_ of your `String` then it's not a valid `String`.